# Binding Service Variable To Controller AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, service, controller

http://jsfiddle.net/9hazjjcc/

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope, myService) {
    $scope.targetMode = myService.targetMode; 
    $scope.myService = myService;
}

myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.targetMode = 2;
});

function ctrlTwo($scope, myService) {
    $scope.addToTargetMode = function() {
    myService.targetMode++;
 }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p>Hello, {{ targetMode }}!</p>
  <p>Hello, {{ myService.targetMode }}!</p>
</div>

<div ng-controller="ctrlTwo">
  <button ng-click="addToTargetMode()">
    Add To Target Mode
  </button>
</div>
```

This JSFiddle says most of it. I would like to use a service variable in the controller to manipulate the view, but I don't want to expose the entire service to the controller because that seems not very Angular-like. Or is that considered best practice?

Ideally, the first paragraph would update to display the targetMode variable from the service whenever it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Your way it's not bad, if your service was created to manage "the target mode", you can use that way, but i think instead of exposing this.targetMode = 2, this is the service function, you can use services like a model pattern, in your service you can do someting like this:

```
myApp.service('myService', function() {
    var targetMode = 2;

    return {
        getTargetMode: function() { return targetMode; }
});
```

You can mix in your services private functions and only expose public, etc etc.

But, in my opinion, due to the context of targetMode, i think it's better to be a controller variable (scope variable i mean), as you know, services not be injected a scope, they don't be as a part of scope cycle, and you are using this variable in the template so i think you want the angular "binding", so it's better to use a scope variable and declared in the controller (maybe in a custom directive depends on each case). This is the angular-way.
If you use a service (non-scope var), you can watch it manually in the controller or as you are doing, you can use a function as a watcher, but using a scope variable is more efficient.

The thing is, your $scope variable that you are using for binding: $scope.addToTargetMode, is declared as a function, right, it's correct because you need to go to the service, in the digest cycle this is less efficient that using directly the value in the controller. Let me explain, in all the digest cycles angular will execute your function. So if you use directly a scope variable (forget the service), the digest cycle will not be an aditional calling because the scope has "his own great manage".
Angular watches by itself the scope variables: Objects, strings, numbers, arrays, and will do "changes" if it changes and you haven't to do anything!, but with scope function variables the angular magic works worst, because in all digest cycles this function will be computed.

So, always you will use a variable for binding, think in controllers, services for example will be good if, you need to get a data from a bbdd or whatever. For sure, this only applies if you are using Angular 1.X.X, Angular 2 is other history